# query to merge or combine first name, middle initial and last name in single column, when Ihave full Middle name in few rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

I am Using Teradata sql assistant.

```
select (A1.first+', '+A1.last+' '+substr(a1.middle,1,1)) as  iName
from tablename A1
```

I am getting this error

> 420:  SQL0420N  Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".  SQLSTATE=22018

But when I process the same query in MS sql server studio, I amable to run,

When I use this query

```
select (A1.first+', '+A1.last+' '+substr(a1.middle,1,1)) as  iName
from tablename A1
```

I get this error,

> 171:  SQL0171N  The data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in position "3" of routine "SUBSTRING" is incorrect. Parameter name: "".  SQLSTATE=42815

Please help me solve this.

Comment: I believe the string concatenation operator in Teradata is `||`, not `+`.

Comment: As the plus sign is numeric operator there's an automatic type cast for first/last/middle to a FLOAT which of course fails. So use Gordon's answer and apply COALESCE(A1.middle,'') in case there's a NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I think the query you want is:

```
select (A1.first || ', ' || A1.last || ' '+substr(a1.middle, 1, 1)) as  iName
from tablename A1;
```